# What does "cycle **on** a vertex set" mean? (Hint from Graph Theory by Diestel)

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm trying to solve an exercise from the book 'Graph Theory' by Diestel, and the hint provided for the exercise includes the following sentence:

> Can $G[P]$ contain a cycle **on** $V(P)$?

What I'd like to know is what exactly this is supposed to mean. Does a cycle **on** a vertex set go through all the vertices of this set, or does it go through a subset of the given vertex set? As far as I can see in the book, the author doesn't really use this terminology anywhere in the section about cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context of the exercise, "a cycle on $V(P)$" can only mean "a cycle whose vertex set is $V(P)$". That is, your first interpretation - that the cycle must go through all the vertices of this set - is the correct one.

The exercise is, in my opinion, misplaced nine chapters off. It is an excellent exercise for making sure that a student of graph theory really understands the proof of Theorem 10.1.1 in Diestel (Dirac's theorem). If you want a further hint, look ahead and read the first page and a half of Chapter 10.

Diestel doesn't use the phrasing "cycle on (a vertex set)" anywhere else in the book, though the phrasing "path on (a vertex set)" occurs once with the same meaning. Personally, if I encountered a sentence like this anywhere else, I would hesitantly guess that the path/cycle has to go through the entire vertex set given, but I wouldn't be confident.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I suspected that this was the intended interpretation, but as you mentioned it's hard to know for sure. Also, it's good to know that there is a hint further on in the book if needed.